# Scipy Curve Fit Global Parameters

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

I'm trying to fit a two global parameters of a galactic model using Scipy curve_fit in python. I have an array of independent variables and an array of dependent variables. The first 1/4 of the data set needs to be fit to a function depending on the two global parameters and two local parameters, the next quarter to another function depending on the two global parameters and two local variables, etc.

Is there anyway that I can write a function that will call the appropriate function with the right index and the global parameters through the entire array.

What I have so far is:

```
   def galaxy_func_inner(time,a,b,c,d):
     telescope_inner = lt.station(rot_angle=c,pol_angle=d)
     power = telescope_inner.calculate_gpowervslstarray(time)[0]
     return a*np.array(power)+b

   def galaxy_func_outer(time,a,b,c,d):
     telescope_outer = lt.station(rot_angle=c,pol_angle=d)
     power = telescope_outer.calculate_gpowervslstarray(time)[0]
     return a*np.array(power)+b

   def galaxy_func_global(time,R,P,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h):
        for t_index in range(len(time)):
           if t_index in range(0,50):
                   return galaxy_func_outer(t_index,a,b,R,P)
           elif t_index in range(50,100):
                   return galaxy_func_outer(t_index,c,d,R,P)
           elif t_index in range(100,150):
                   return galaxy_func_inner(t_index,e,f,R,P)
           elif t_index in range(150,200):
                   return galaxy_func_inner(t_index,g,h,R,P)
```

The problem is that this only fits the first time but the whole time array, and the single point is only fitted to the corresponding model point and not the whole array. Any help as to how to reformulate this? I've tried to reformulate it as:

```
 def galaxy_func_global(xdata,R,P,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h):
     return galaxy_func_outer(xdata[0:50],a,b,R,P),galaxy_func_outer(xdata[50:100],c,d,R,P),galaxy_func_inner(xdata[100:150],e,f,R,P),galaxy_func_inner(xdata[150:200],g,h,R,P)
```

but I get the error:

```
File "galaxy_calibration.py", line 117, in <module>
    popt,pcov = curve_fit(galaxy_func_global,xdata,ydata)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scipy-0.14.0.dev_7cefb25-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg/scipy/optimize/minpack.py", line 555, in curve_fit
    res = leastsq(func, p0, args=args, full_output=1, **kw)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scipy-0.14.0.dev_7cefb25-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg/scipy/optimize/minpack.py", line 369, in leastsq
    shape, dtype = _check_func('leastsq', 'func', func, x0, args, n)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scipy-0.14.0.dev_7cefb25-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg/scipy/optimize/minpack.py", line 20, in _check_func
    res = atleast_1d(thefunc(*((x0[:numinputs],) + args)))
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scipy-0.14.0.dev_7cefb25-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg/scipy/optimize/minpack.py", line 445, in _general_function
    return function(xdata, *params) - ydata
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (4,) (191,)
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You might get a quicker answer if you provide a [mcve]. Something's not clear to me, for instance: does `galaxy_func_inner/outer` expect a time, or an integer index as first parameter? The naming of the variables would suggest the former, but when you call these functions in your `global` functions you give them `t_index` rather than t.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to cut your input data into 4 batches (based on the index of the `time` points) and process the data depending on the batches, *then* return the results in a single array, then you can do this:

```
def galaxy_func_global(time,R,P,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h):
    return np.concatenate([galaxy_func_outer(time[0:50],a,b,R,P),
                          galaxy_func_outer(time[50:100],c,d,R,P),
                          galaxy_func_inner(time[100:150],e,f,R,P),
                          galaxy_func_inner(time[150:200],g,h,R,P)])
```

This will slice into your `time` array to pick out each slice of interest, then call the appropriate function for each piece. It seems to me that these functions return simple `np.array`s, which can be concatenated to get a single array as result.

(I just realized that I could've just said "what you tried was almost perfect, but you need to concatenate the resulting arrays into a single array":)

---

Note that there are at least two ways in which you can have dimensioning problems.

Firstly, you should make sure that the return value of both of your functions (`galaxy...inner/outer()`) is a 1d numpy array. Otherwise you'll run into problems with your global return value.

Secondly, every fitting method expects a function the return value of which has the same size (shape) as the input variable, for obvious reasons. So you can also run into problems with your current code if `time` is not exactly 200 elements long, since your output will be truncated to 200 elements even if `time` is longer. At least you should put

```
galaxy_func_inner(time[150:],g,h,R,P)
```

into your last function call to catch *all the remaining points* of `time`, but if you want to do it properly, call

```
def galaxy_func_global(time,R,P,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h):
    inds=np.floor(np.linspace(0,len(time)-1,5))
    return np.concatenate([galaxy_func_outer(time[0:inds[1]],a,b,R,P),
                      galaxy_func_outer(time[inds[1]:inds[2]],c,d,R,P),
                      galaxy_func_inner(time[inds[2]:inds[3]],e,f,R,P),
                      galaxy_func_inner(time[inds[3]:],g,h,R,P)])
```

Also note that your original error is formally of this kind:

```
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scipy-0.14.0.dev_7cefb25-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg/scipy/optimize/minpack.py", line 445, in _general_function
    return function(xdata, *params) - ydata
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (4,) (191,)
```

This tells you that python couldn't subtract `ydata` from `function(xdata,*params)` (i.e. your fitting model) because one is of length 4 while the other is of length 191. This is because if your function calls `return a,b,c,d`, then it will return a *tuple* `(a,b,c,d)`, so the return value will have a length of 4. It's more interesting that your `ydata` has length 191, this might mean that you'll still run into an error.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Doesn't np.concatenate only take two arguments - not four as you have it written?

Comment: Also with regards of the ydata having length of 191, my data set is truncated into [0:49],[49:98],[98:144],[144:191]. But the problem seems to be that its trying to fit the whole ydata with a xdata of one of these subsizes (which is what we want):                                                                                                     

     def galaxy_func_global(xdata,R,P,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h):
             return np.array((galaxy_func_outer(xdata[0:49],a,b,R,P),galaxy_func_outer(xdata[49:98],c,d,R,P),galaxy_func_inner(xdata[98:144],e,f,R,P),galaxy_func_inner(xdata[144:191],g,h,R,P)))

Comment: @Emma518, 1. try out `concatenate` yourself on a test case: `np.concatenate([1,3],[2,5],[3,4],[6,7])`. 2. I'm sorry but I don't understand what you're saying. Have you *tried* what I suggested?

Comment: I have tried this but the error I get is my first comment: TypeError: function takes at most 2 arguments (4 given)

Comment: @Emma518 yeah, sorry about that! You have to put all the arguments of `concatenate` into a list... You're right, my bad:) I edited my answer, should be fine now. Next time start with the error and I won't assume you're wrong;)